# How do I resolve a unresolved dependency error after using Composer to install modules?

Tags: composer

I'm going to pull my hair out if I stare at this problem any longer. I've seen the similar questions and tried everything but I can't fix this issue with module dependency versions.

I'm using `Composer require drupal/<module_name>` and I've tried including specific versions too but that hasn't worked. I see that the current version number isn't being displayed at the end of the error message which makes me wonder whether the system knows what version is even installed?

I also don't understand how so many modules can be asking for different versions of the same dependency. How can you possibly resolve that :|

I should also add that I was in the process of converting manually installed modules into Composer controlled dependencies. I'm not sure if that would make a difference.

It really seems to me that Drupal doesn't know what versions of Modifiers and Paragraphs are installed but I don't see how.

[image: The error]

Comment: I'd always start with `rm composer.lock && rm -rf vendor/ && composer install -n` on a local copy of the site, followed by `drush cr && drush -y updb`.

Comment: Also check that composer (the tool) itself is up to date!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried the above but even after using `composer clear-cache` it still shows "cloning XXX from cache" which is odd. The update still shows the "unresolved dependency" messages and the update looks like this:


`>  [notice] Update started: paragraphs_library_update_8004
>  [error]  Cannot add field paragraphs_library_item_revision_field_data.label: field already exists. 
>  [error]  Update failed: paragraphs_library_update_8004 
[error]  Update aborted by: paragraphs_library_update_8004 
[error]  Finished performing updates.`

Comment: I've just edited the question above with updated details

Answer (score -1):

So, the system couldn't decide what version of the modules were installed. Here is a fix:

https://www.drupal.org/project/modifiers/issues/3052416

Basically, install ***Git Deploy*** module to add versioning details to modules .info files.